# Akka Streams running on cluster nodes

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-cluster

I am trying to understand the scaling part of Akka Streams I have seen various replies here, but still fail to understand how this functionality is accomplished.

There are ActorPublisher/Subscribers which from what I understand are meant to interact with the stream, but at the same time it says that these can not be remote.

How would I accomplish being able to use akka clusters toegether with streams? Do I have to let the GraphStage "outsource" its work to a remote actor? Or can the graphStage itself be run on a cluster node?

My use case is having a pipeline containing several heavy calculation stages with joins and merges and possibly some of these stages would need to be distributed.

**Update**
According to this [Crawling the Web with Akka Streams](http://tech.smartling.com/crawling-the-web-with-akka-streams/) I see that a single graph can not span several clusters. What would be the way in this case to horizontally scale?

Comment: you can only use streams locally. Whatever you do between remote nodes has to be done the "old" way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

akka-streams doesn't support clustering yet. I suggest look at the [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) as middleware for transport if you need some clustering solution, and  [reactive-kafka](https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka). But, of course, you can implement your own transport layer with actors and run it in Akka cluster.